# YouTube data Api for videos under particular category

Tags: youtube-data-api

I am trying to fetch the 25 each videos under particular category, but i am struggle to form YouTube data API, can anyone help me to form.

I have got category list using categories API, but i am struggle to fetch videos of particular category.

Comment: please mention the language

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Videos List API
with the parameters `chart=mostPopular` and `videoCategoryId=<id>`

for example

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&chart=mostPopular&videoCategoryId=10&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

Comment: I have tried this one, but it wouldn't retrieves videos belongs to particular category?? category 45 videos coming under category 1